# Do rules revert to 4 player rules midgame if someone gets eliminated?

Tags: twilight-imperium, twilight-imperium-3rd-edition

When playing a 5 or more player game of Twilight Imperium and someone is completely removed from the game, do you revert to picking two strategy cards each as per a 4 player game?

Comment: This is covered in the [FAQ on Fantasy Flight's website](http://new.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_minisite_sec.asp?eidm=21&esem=4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, nothing changes. The [TI3 FAQ](http://new.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Twilight%20Imperium%203/ti3faq.pdf) puts it fairly straightforwardly on the left hand side of page 2:

> #### Elimination
>
> A player who controls no planets and has no units on the board
>   is eliminated from the game. He cannot play Action Cards or
>   choose Strategy Cards. After a player has been eliminated, the
>   other players continue the game normally, **with no changes
>   to the number of Strategy Cards taken, etc.** When a player is
>   eliminated, all his Action Cards are discarded and all of his
>   race's Trade Agreements are removed from the game.

Once a player's eliminated, everyone plays by the same rules as they have been the whole game. You don't revert to rules for the current lower number of players.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, a player cannot be eliminated from the game. He can lose all of his plastic figures, but still after each round he participates in the strategy- and action card distribution, by which he can affect the gameplay.

Conclusion from this would be that if the house wants to enable dropping a player, then it's house-rules specific.

Comment: http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/529087/player-elimination

Comment: Players _do_ get eliminated completely; it _is_ in the rules.